# pandas df: change values in column A only for rows that are unique in column B

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It sounds like a trivial question and I'd expected to find a quick answer, but didn't have much success.
I have the dataframe population and columns A and B. I want to change the value in B to 1 only to those rows with unique value in column A (currently all rows in B hold the value 0).

I tried:

```
small_towns = population['A'].value_counts() == 1
population[population['A'] in small_towns]['B']=1
```

and got: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I also tried:

```
population.loc[population['A'].value_counts() == 1, population['B']] = 1
```

and got the same error with an aditional: pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError:

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with **`keep = False`** 
this returns a `Series` with `True` on all duplicates values ​​and `False` on the rest. We can put 1 in rows with `True` using [DataFrame.loc[]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
population.loc[~population['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 'B'] = 1
#population.loc[~population.duplicated(subset = 'A', keep=False), 'B'] = 1
```

We can also use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) or [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
population['B'] = population['B'].where(population['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 1)
#population['B'] = population['B'].mask(~population['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 1)
```

**but if you want to create a serie `B` with 1 or 0 you can simply do:**

```
population['B'] = (~population['A'].duplicated(keep=False)).astype(int)
```

or

```
population['B'] = np.where(population['A'].duplicated(keep=False), 0, 1)
```